# Marcar solo un checkbox de varios que contiene un array

Tags: php, html, array, checkbox

Tengo una tabla con varios checkbox que se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se pinta con el siguiente código

```html
$sql = "SELECT id, codigo, descripcion FROM temas_n2 WHERE id_tema_n1 = " . $id_N1; $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); foreach ($query as $key => $value_N2) { $id_N2 = $value_N2['id']; ?>

<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value_N2['id']; ?>" name="id_N2[]"> <strong><?php echo $value_N2['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
  <td><strong><?php echo $value_N2['descripcion']; ?> </strong></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N2[]"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N2[]" checked=""></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N2[]"></td>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, codigo, descripcion FROM temas_n3 WHERE id_tema_n2 = " . $id_N2;
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

foreach ($query as $key => $value_N3) {
  $id_N3 = $value_N3['id']
?>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value_N3['id']; ?>" name="id_N3[]"> <strong><?php echo $value_N3['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $value_N3['descripcion']; ?>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N3[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N3[]" checked=""></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N3[]"></td>
  </tr>

  <?php
 }//End foreach TEMA_N0
?>
<?php
}//End foreach TEMA_N1
?>
```

Se requiere que solo marque uno de los tres por cada fila de la tabla, los checks como se puede apreciar es un array, cuando aplico el siguiente código:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
</script> 

<script>
  $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {

    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) 
    {

    // set all elements matching the name to unchecked        
    $("input:checkbox[name='check_N2[]']").prop("checked", false)

    // set the orginally checked box back to 'checked'       
    $box.prop("checked", true);
   } 
   else 
   {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
   }
});
</script>
```

Solo permite marcar uno en toda la tabla, y lo requerido es marcar solo uno pero por cada una de las filas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los puedes agrupar por tr en lugar de buscar por todos los checkbox, en este caso se uso `closest()` para encontrar el `tr` en el que se encuentra y `find()` para encontrar todos los checkbox solo de ese `tr`

```js
  $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {

    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      // set all elements matching the name to unchecked        
      $(this).closest('tr').find("input:checkbox[name='check_N3[]']").prop("checked", false)

    // set the orginally checked box back to 'checked'       
    $box.prop("checked", true);
   } 
   else 
   {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table order=1 frame=void rules=rows>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N3[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N3[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N3[]">
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N3[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N3[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N3[]">
     </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```